# I can not select/highlight text in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, textselection

So, I've developed this site, but you can't select some of the text, it isn't the biggest problem but I would like to know what is causing it.

This is the site (http://quinnkeaveney.com/setoff)

The text that you can't select is the large main text in the center-right.

It doesn't appear to be a z-index issue or a user-select issue. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It has something to do with Javascript. What is your Javascript doing?

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: you must have used some code to diable the selection??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in you javascript:

```
$(function() {$( ".draggable" ).draggable({ handle: ".navnav" });$( "div, p" ).disableSelection();});
```

You select all divs and disable selections for them:

```
$( "div, p" ).disableSelection();});
```